# Difference in the meaning of kernel, filter, and dictionary atoms

Tags: filters, wavelet, kernel

While reading literature on wavelets, I have encountered keywords *filters* and *dictionary atoms* and their exact meaning is confusing for me. Basically, one can use them interchangeably and I won't see a problem. the following text is an example

> Our objective in this section is to develop a method to generate a
>   system of ***filters*** such that (i) the ***filters*** are translated versions of
>   each other in the graph spectral domain, and (ii) the $M \cdot N$
>   ***dictionary atoms*** constructed by applying each generalized
>   translation operator $T_{i}$ to each ***filter*** form a tight frame. More
>   precisely, given an upper bound, $\lambda_{\text { max }},$ on the
>   spectrum and a desired number of filters, $M,$ we want to find a
>   ***kernel*** $\widehat{g}^{U}(\cdot)$ and constants $a$ and $A$ such that . . .

Would someone be able to comment on the how kernel, filter, and dictionary atoms differ with each other in this context? Thanks!

---

The text is from [Spectrum-Adapted Tight Graph Wavelet and Vertex-Frequency Frames (DOI:10.1109/TSP.2015.2424203)](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7088640/).

Comment: a bit of context would be very helpful; as far as I can see, *atom* is a term from measure theory, or maybe set theory. The analytic tone of the rest of this suggests we're dealing with someone thinking in measure theory, but then again, the combination with the very discrete-math word *dictionary* implies we're more in the realm of set theory...

Comment: *Kernel* is even worse: in the context of image filtering, you can basically exchange *filter impulse response* by kernel (that's probably taken from the integral transform meaning of *kernel*), but in algebraic contextes, it means sets that map to zero. In other words, we'd probably have to read the chapters leading up to your paragraph to be sure how to answer your question. **Without knowing at least the title and field of the text you're reading, I'm afraid it'll be impossible to help you with certainty, and "likely" is the best answer you could get.**

Comment: A filter is a procedure mathematician applied to a signal to remove some "components" of it. Generally, filters are designed as linear element, so that, if the input signal is $S$, the output signal is $S*K$, where $K$ is known as the kernel. Kernel is a vector in a dimension, matrix in two dimension and tensor in three dimensions. Now, if you have one signal 1D or 2D and then applied one or various kernels, the outputs can be organized in an array known as "dictionary atoms", this dictionary has the representation of your signal and can be used in test phase to classifier a test signal.

Comment: $*$ means convolution operation

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks! I added the link to the paper.

Comment: @RogerFigueroaQuintero Thanks! This seems more meaningful in this context, I'm going to read parts of the paper again with your respond in the mind and see if it makes perfect sense.

Comment: When the paper is published, I suggest to use its full title and DOI for long term access: [Spectrum-Adapted Tight Graph Wavelet and
Vertex-Frequency Frames (DOI:10.1109/TSP.2015.2424203)](https://doi.org/10.1109/TSP.2015.2424203)

Comment: This can also be expressed in the opposite direction: a filter is used to highlight certain characteristics of a signal, for example, a  bandpass filter for a one-dimensional signal highlights the components of that band. In the case of two dimensions, there are some filters widely used in image processing such as the Gaussian kernel used to highlight structures known as blobs, or Sobel or Laplacian kernel used to highlight edges. In conclusion, removing components from a signal is equivalent to highlighting other components (those that are not removed)